# Indexes in a big table. (About 400 mil of rows)

Tags: sql-server-2012, index-tuning, table

I have a little deal. I have this table in a SQL Server 2012 Standard edition database. The table contains about 400 mil of rows.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prodeje]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [partner] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [id_paragon] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [typ_pohybu] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [store] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [datetime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
    [id_prod] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [customer] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [price_per_unit] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [stock_price] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [pc] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [amount] [decimal](16, 4) NULL,
    [action] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [action_cupon] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [bonus_gratis] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [fin_sleva] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [exclude] [tinyint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It's a table with sales. So most of the query will include column partner, store, date, id_prod, price per unit * amount and distinct count on column id_paragon for baskets. Column id_prod is foreign key for table with products. Column exclude is column with information if the row is good. All query will contains in where clause exclude=0.

And I am thinking about indexes. Because it's more usually use part of the year, so my first think was that i will do clustered index on column date. And in query i query first only data what i need. So I will query on few mil of rows and it will be quick. And index for id_prod. But I think that is not good way to do the indexes. So I have questions for you, what indexes will you do on this table.

If you need more info write a comment. I will add what you want for think about it.

Thanks

Comment: What are you optimizing for? Read speed? Write speed? Disk space used? Pick priorities.

Comment: I want to optimizing that table for read speed. Write speed is good for now. Scripts insert about 80k rows per batch. (About 6 batch in one day). Disk space doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are optimizing for reads you could simply add one optimal index per query. So if your query is

```
select price_per_unit from Sales where exclude = 0 and partner = 42
```

Create the index `(exclude, partner) include (price_per_unit)`.

You say that writes and disk spaces are not of significant concern. So add the optimal indexes to support your reads.